# Flutter: How to make an infinite loop in listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to make an infinite loop in my listview, when index is at the end and user continue to scroll to left the next item will be the first one

```
ListView.builder(
                controller: _controller,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: packs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  _index = index;
                  print(index);
                  return Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
```

I want user can infinite swipe, how can I do ?

Answer (score 3):

```
  ListView.builder(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                // itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final i = index % items.length;//<----to the right
                  final item = items[i];
                  return ItemSwiper(
                    item: item,
                    onTab: () => _.goToDetailItem(item: item),
                  );
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove **itemCount** and try...
But you cannot use a particular index, just showing a widget on that position.
And you can print **Index** but make sure that you don't use an index with any external data source having limited data.

```
ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text('Item ${index + 1}'),
        );
      },
    )
```

Comment: It works but only for the end, if index == 0 and I swipe right it is not infinite :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use the package [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) to achieve this for both directions